# Im trying to insert an image into a html document but its not working, It says my image file doesnt exist

Tags: html, css

Within my folder called wren assignment I have two files. A html file called wren.html and a jpeg image called marsh_wren_thumbnail.jpg

When I run the code in google the outline of the image is there but theres no image. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong because I followed exactly how W3 schools said to insert an image and the image name in the code is exactly the same as it is in my file. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">

<head>

<meta charset = "UTF-8">

</head>


<body>

<h1>The Wren</h1>

 <img src="marsh_wren_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Wren" style="width:304px;height:228px;">


<h3>Other Names:</h3>

 <ul>
  <li>Wran</li>
  <li>Sally</li>
  <li>Chitty Wren</li>
  <li>Stumpy Toddy</li>
 </ul>
  
  
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have marsh_wren_thumbnail.jpg in same folder as your HTML file. For example:

```
Project-folder
 | index.html
 | marsh_wren_thumbnail.jpg
```

Comment: It is in the same folder. Within the folder practical wren contains the wren.html and the image file marsh_wren_thumbnail.jpg

Comment: When you open console in browser do you have error like this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"?

Comment: No, the list and the headers work, its just the image doesnt, its just a box with the word "Wren" in the top left hand corner. Not sure what it is, probably something small but I cant see whats wrong.

Comment: I know that you see header but when you see "box with the word "Wren"" it means that your image is not loading properly because you didn't put your image at right place.  Try to open console (click right click on page and inspect element then position on console tab and refresh tab). You will probably see 404 code. Check your image name in file system is matched with src of img tag and put HTML and image in same folder.